# Web services with JSON Parsing

Tags: iphone, json

In my app Web services are created in dot net and i am consuming those and I am getting response.In that all the fields like company,type,location everything are strings and there is no problem with this..And there is one more field called Exhibit number actually it is a Integer but they are created as string only.While I am displaying this it is showing zero instead of that number..     Here is my code...

```
//Storing into Array
[SurveyFilesArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dic objectForKey:@"FileName"],@"FileName",[dic objectForKey:@"ExibhitNumber"],@"ExhibitNumber",[dic objectForKey:@"Description"],@"Description",[dic objectForKey:@"FileQuality"],@"FileQuality",nil]];

//Retrieving from Array..
NSLog(@"???%@???",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[SurveyFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ExibhitNumber"]intValue]]);
NSLog(@"%d",[[[SurveyFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ExibhitNumber"]intValue]);
```

Comment: So what's the JSON? Show some (**not all!**) of it.

Comment: This is the data sample....      <Description>Housekeeping</Description> <ExibhitNumber>1</ExibhitNumber> <FileName>housekeeping3.jpg</FileName> <FileQuality>Low</FileQuality> –

Comment: XML only  I am storing in dictionary so that it is becoming JSON..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in your code.

In the order of your code:
`Ex-ib-hit-Number`
`Ex-hib-it-Number`

These are 2 different strings.

In your example code you save it correctly written as `Ex-hib-it`. But you try to access it with `ex-ib-hit` afterwards. This cannot work.

Comment: This is the data sample....          <Description>Housekeeping</Description>
<ExibhitNumber>1</ExibhitNumber>
<FileName>housekeeping3.jpg</FileName>
<FileQuality>Low</FileQuality>

Comment: Element Name is ExhibitNumber..And I am using key also ExhibitNumber to store in dictionary

Comment: In your example code you save it correctly written as `Ex-hib-it`. But you try to access it with `ex-ib-hit` afterwards. This cannot work.

Comment: Ya,Sorry for asking such a silly question, i missed speeling some how